# When to use synthetic data and when to use regularization parameters to avoid the over fitting and which is better?

Tags: machine-learning, synthetic-data

Can anyone explain me when to consider generating the synthetic data or when to consider regularization parameters to reduce the error so the machine learning model will not overfit

Comment: As far as I understand, we generate synthetic data for model evaluation.

Comment: Usually you use synthetic data only when you do not have real data. Usually you should be able to solve your problem without synthetic data. Using regularization parameters is one technique for some algorithms which tries to limit overfitting. One other situation where you use synthetic data (maybe this is what you are referring to) is when you have an unbalanced training set. If you only 5 positive examples and 10k negative, then your algorithm will not notice any interesting patterns. So you create synthetic positive ones in the hopes that then it will notice real distinguishing features.

Comment: If by "synthetic data" you mean SMOTE, I'd say "never".  I would however use synthetic data to induce invariances into the model (e.g. rotational invariance by rotating existing images), but regularisation is not an alternative implementation for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with a time-consuming procedure for labeling, then you need to generate images synthetically for the training path. In the validation and test path, it is easier to label images since the number of inputs is few. Also, the model is robust if it validated by real images and works fine.

Comment: semi-spervised learning may be a better approach, where you give the model both labelled and unlabelled examples